# C++ Weird problem with ifstream >> memory and OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, opengl, ifstream

I'm using a loop to create a char array image, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++)    
{
    for(int j = 0; j < SCREEN_WIDTH; j++)        
    {                   
        image[i * SCREEN_WIDTH + j][0] = PIXEL_RED[0];        
        image[i * SCREEN_WIDTH + j][1] = PIXEL_RED[1];        
        image[i * SCREEN_WIDTH + j][2] = PIXEL_BLUE[2];
        image[i * SCREEN_WIDTH + j][3] = PIXEL_RED[3];        
    };        
};
```

I send it to an OpenGL frame buffer, like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

This works in most places.

However, it doesn't work where I want it to. I have narrowed it down to the following issue.

In the instance where this doesn't work properly, there is a scene loader function to precedes it.

If I include this line in the scene loader

```
PCL::AtomicTypes::float_32 placementData[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    source >> placementData[i];
};
```

I don't see the texture. Xcode also reports memory usage as ~87mb.

If I comment it out, like so:

```
PCL::AtomicTypes::float_32 placementData[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    //source >> placementData[i];
};
```

I do see the texture. Also, Xcode reports memory usage as ~40mb.

Also, if I make this part read 13 times:

```
PCL::AtomicTypes::float_32 placementData[13];
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    source >> placementData[i];
};
```

I do see the texture. Similarly, Xcode reports memory usage as ~40mb.

But this obviously causes the next components to load incorrectly.

The scene loader loads 25 files, all of which contain a collection of floats, integers and strings. There is one for the player, four for lights, and twenty for objects (balls).

The player one looks like this:

```
Player
100
2
0
1.0 0.0 0.0 9.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1
1.0
2
0.1 1000.0 1.25 60 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I can't post the full code as the engine is now quite involved. I'm mostly looking for suggestions of where to look.

I've used instruments in Profiler, it reports no memory leaks.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

I'm working in c++, in Xcode. I use OpenGL, glfw, glad, and stbimage.h

Weirdly, if I break the loop up and have:

```
PCL::AtomicTypes::float_32 placementData[8];                                    
for(PCL::DefinedTypes::Iterator i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    //3, 4, 6, 7, 13
    source >> placementData[i];
};
 source >> placementData[7];
```

It works fine. The numbers in the comment are the number of loop iterations that cause it to work without problems... I don't understand it at all. But I am sure it is something simple I'm missing / messing up.

Edited for easier reading (I hope).

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more reader friendly [ask]. No wall of text, just information about your problem. No complex sentences about nothing. Create logical paragraphs (add empty lines). Most important provide [mcve] I recommend to use https://wandbox.org/ or https://godbolt.org/ for that.

Comment: Much better! But still most important things are missing! How first listing is related to the third one? Note that your modification makes this loop useless (it does nothing). How this file looks like is it a text file?

Comment: What is in `placementData` after you read in the 8 elements? Is it what you expect it to be? I'd double check all the routines in the scene loader that read the files (and that the files are all correct). It's very easy to get a ifstream cursor in the wrong place.

Comment: The placement data is exactly what I expect it to be. It's in a switch that uses an int from the file to determine which component is being loaded, and then loads it in a similar manner to the placement data. Every bit of data for every component of every entity is correct. And I can use the data correctly in the renderer.

Comment: You should try using the debugger, you may have a memory overwrite somewhere and the best way to catch that is with a debugger.

Comment: How is `placementData` related to `image`? How do you convert the `float32` in `placementData` to the unsigned byte for `glTexImage2D`?

Comment: PlacementData has nothing to do with the image. Eventually it will, but for now placementData is used to position the camera, lights and models for my pbrrender. The image at this point is just those nested loops. The Pixel typeset there is just an unsigned char[4].

Comment: I enabled guard Malloc to see where overwrites may be occurring and it’s thrown up an error already. So I’ll persevere with that for a bit and see if I can narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was indeed a memory overwrite problem.

The cause of the problem was in my use of std::string, which I only use to translate lines extracted from getline() to my own fixed-length string class.

It turns out that I am an idiot, and can't write loops properly... I was incorrectly copying a c_str(), and causing undefined behaviour.

So, I will consider this answered.

Comment: I'll just delete that comment. Feel free to fix the answer.